# TDD in asp.net mvc textbox

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

how can i develop a TDD to test a textbox value (for an e-mail)

i'm using  ASP.NET mvc  (c#)

Also, some advices on how to tackle the subject (TDD in ASP.net mvc) are welcomed.

Thanks for helping

Comment: Red - Green - Refactor

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a normal TDD you should not have a test which is depend on a dynamic value of TextBox but you should write different tests for all situations which may happen.
If you mean you want to see the value of a textbox for a certain value you can do like that:
Assume you have class:

```
   public class ContactData{
                              public String TextBoxValue{get;set;}
                           }
```

then you assign TextBoxValue to your textbox:
In your test code you must do like below:

```
        HomeController controller = new HomeController();

        ViewResult result = controller.Contact() as ViewResult;
        var modelObject=(ContactData)result.Model;
        Assert.AreEqual(modelObject.TextBoxValue,"TestValue");
```

Comment: actually what i mean is that  in a Model i have a mail_adress whith an attribut validation  ([Required][..] )   in the View  i use validationsummary() for validation 

My question is how can i test that 

it's simple for me if i write a validations code in the controller ) but whith validationsummary()  is  complicated

Comment: Do you mean you want to make sure the textbox value is in email format and you want to check it out inside the controller action?

Comment: no i want to use html.validationsummary()   and  i want  to test that with unit tests

Answer (score 0):

What you are asking for is quite a broad topic, however follow the steps below to get started:

1. Write a Unit test against the required feature.
2. Run the test - this should fail as you haven't implemented anything.
3. Implement the feature required.
4. Retest - this should result in a pass.
5. Refactor your implementation and test.
6. Retest to confirm your refactor hasn't broken the test itself.

For more information take a look at these resources:

[Introduction to TDD](http://www.agiledata.org/essays/tdd.html)

[Using TDD with ASP.NET MVC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff847525(v=vs.100).aspx)